# Modify Fetchxml query based on the parameter values

Tags: sql, dynamics-crm, crm, rdl, fetchxml

Below is my XML for rdl report
where @AccountType is an option value list as 1(franchise),2(customer),3(both)

```
<DataSet Name="dtaReport">
  <Query>
    <DataSourceName>dsOpenWorksCRM</DataSourceName>
    <QueryParameters>
     <QueryParameter Name="@AccountType">
        <Value>=Parameters!AccountType.Value</Value>
        <rd:UserDefined>true</rd:UserDefined>
      </QueryParameter>
    </QueryParameters>
<CommandText>
      &lt;fetch version="1.0" output-format="xml-platform" mapping="logical" distinct="true"&gt;
      &lt;entity name="account"&gt;
      &lt;attribute name="name" /&gt;
      &lt;attribute name="accountid" /&gt;
      &lt;filter type="and"&gt;
      &lt;condition attribute="plus_accounttype" operator="eq" value="@AccountType" /&gt;
      &lt;/filter&gt;
      &lt;/entity&gt;
      &lt;/fetch&gt;
    </CommandText>
```

If I select either 1 or 2, then it works fine with the above query, if I select 3, I need to change the above query which returns the both 1and 2 type records. I'm guessing to write an if condition to change the above operator to "in" if I select 3 but not sure how to achieve this
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a multi-select dropdown and that parameter can be used along with `in` operator of fetchxml query.

You have to check the setting - ‘Allow multiple values’. [Read more](https://www.daymandynamics.com/how-to-add-an-option-set-as-a-parameter-in-a-ssrs-report/)

[image]